# Does this "coming up with" make sense?

Tags: writing

> What I try to do here is to borrow from Confucius the doctrine of
>   “benevolence”, and then modify it in light of the significant and
>   exigent  issues we face nowadays, finally **coming up with** a new
>   doctrine of  “benevolence”. (self-made)

Does the "coming up with" make sense to you? My interpretation of what I am going to do is too complicated, involving three consecutive verbs, so I write three verbs in a temporaray order, and changing the last verb into the form of a participle. Can I do this?

Comment: Yes. And why not?

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is grammatical. Whether it will be effective depends on who your readers are. If it’s for a general readership, you might want to consider breaking the sentence up into two or three shorter ones. If it’s in an academic paper, *coming up with* may be a little too colloquial. Alternatives are *developing, producing* and *proposing*. These might need some consequent changes to the rest of the sentence.